# SQL How to select the value of the end of season(every three month)

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Supposed I have some data as below:

```
    code     vol    val      num     test_date
   ------------------------------------------
1   00001    500    0.1      111      20180105
2   00001    1000   0.2      222      20180304
3   00001    200    0.1      111      20180330
4   00001    400    0.3      222      20180601
5   00001    200    0.2      333      20180630
```

My expected result is

```
    code     vol    val      num     test_date
   ------------------------------------------
1   00001    200    0.1      111      20180330
2   00001    200    0.2      333      20180630
3   00001    200    0.2      333      20180928 -- Max(val) only 0928, there is no data in 20180930
4   00001    200    0.2      333      20181231
```

I would like to select the max(val) for the month in '3, 6, 9 12', how to query in MySQL, thanks  so much for any advice.

Comment: Please show your desired results.  Also, the explanation is not clear.

Comment: I already updated, thanks so much

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `quarter` function available in `mysql`.

```
select * from test t1
inner join (
  select  quarter(test_date) qtr, max(val) val from test
  group by quarter(test_date)) t2 on t2.val = t1.val and t2.qtr = quarter(t1.test_date)
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=JkpzHkt8rj).

Answer (score 1):

Since your dates are in numeric `YYYYMMDD` form, you can convert them to a "season" by integer dividing the date by 300. You can then find the maximum `test_date` per season and `JOIN` that back to the original table to get the values for that date:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM data d
JOIN (SELECT test_date DIV 300 AS quarter, MAX(test_date) AS max_date
      FROM data
      GROUP BY quarter) m ON m.max_date = d.test_date
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=32b618166aa460210030b07397f6918a)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . If you want the maximum value for each quarter, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by year(test_date), quarter(test_date) order by val desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want the value on the last day of the quarter that is in the data, then use `order by test_date desc` instead:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by year(test_date), quarter(test_date) order by test_date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```